# Javascript Alert Causes an Error with Watir Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, watir

This code creates a new instance of Firefox (37.0.2) using Watir-Rails (1.2.1). It is supposed to click on a link that brings up an alert dialog. It works perfectly until reaching `lo.click`, where it throws an Unexpected modal dialog error, which then closes the alert popup and terminates the test. I've been looking for a way to handle the error, but rescuing from Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError won't work since the the dialog is closed out before entering the rescue block. This code worked with Watir-Webdriver, but I had to stop using that gem for other reasons. Is there a way to get Watir-Rails to acknowledge and close the popup without this error?

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto new_user_sessions_path
lo = browser.link :href => '/user_sessions'
lo.click
if browser.alert.exists?
  browser.alert.ok
end
```

Comment: Are you sure the code works in Watir-Webdriver but not Watir-Rails? Unless you are using IE, Watir-Rails should be using Watir-Webdriver (ie it seems a bit odd that you have a different behaviour with/without Rails).

Comment: It does work on Watir-Webdriver, but i do have to change the new_user_sessions_path to a url when I'm using Watir-Webdriver instead of Watir-Rails